# Implement PartitionStrategy in Gremlin JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I'm developing a multi-tenant service that utilizes a graph database. I want to store multiple tenants in a single cluster to reduce costs. However, I want to ensure that their resources are isolated. I know in Gremlin that one can use the PartitionStrategy to cause traversals to only explore certain subgraphs. I'm using NodeJS and can't seem to find a PartitionStrategy object. Is there a way to implement it or create a custom class that carries out the same functionality? Also, would labeling every node with a `:Tenant` property suffice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Until the functionality of [TINKERPOP-2054](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2054) is implemented it will not be possible to specify `TraversalStrategy` implementations of any sort with Gremlin in Javascript. It's not an especially hard thing to implement actually...it is mostly implementing the serialization infrastructure to make it all work I think.

You could implement your own paritioning but it would mean that you would have to write your Gremlin in such a way to respect your partitioning semantics. You could add a `:Tenant` property but you would have to always make sure that your application added it to all the appropriate vertices/edges for a particular tenant and then you would have to ensure that all of your traversals include filters based on that property when you were doing reads. `PartitionStrategy` abstracts all of those concerns away so that you don't need to muddy up your Gremlin with such worries.

Comment: Looking at the code: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/jsdocs/3.4.6/process_traversal-strategy.js.html I can't really see anything about Partitions. It doesn't even exists, and if it did, I'm not sure that AWS Neptune would support it.

Comment: it was just added recently and will be available in 3.4.9 - https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6535763e63ac010d63aca55788a92345a1178c3a/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/traversal-strategy.js#L112-L123

Comment: Hopefully AWS will upgrade :)